# using MouseOver in StackPanel WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have just started learning `WPF` and trying to hide a `StackPanel` during `MouseOver`. Below is the code that I use. I can only see the `Panel` flickering when mouse is placed on it but, it doesn't hide completely. Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance.

```
             <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```

Stackpanel:

```
<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource myStyle}">

// Child controls

</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the StackPanel is hidden, the `IsMouseOver` property toggles to `false`, which makes the StackPanel visible again.

You might set the `Opacity` property instead of `Visibility`:

```
<Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Or, as pointed out in the other answer, declare just one Trigger for `IsMouseOver == true`:

```
<Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Clemens has already answered your question, but just FYI when you are triggering on a Boolean value, you don't need a trigger for *both* states. Just set a single trigger for the **true** or **false** state, then when the state no longer applies the properties that were changed by the setters in the trigger will revert back to their previous values. This will cut down on the amount of XAML you need to write.

Comment: Yes.. I realized it later though.